# How would i notify user of unsaved changes in DataGridView DataTable when closing?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview that is showing tables from SQL database. I can edit this tables. Then i have a button that saves this changes, and updates this table  in SQL Server database.

How would i detect changes to table and notify user when he closes the form or goes to another table, that he didnt save his changes?
The code behind the notifiying window for unsaved changes would be something like this:

```
 if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save your changes!", "Save changes", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);
            DataTable dt;
            sda.Update(dt);
            MessageBox.Show("Changes saved");
        }
```

Comment: In case you are using `System.Data.DataTable`, note that this class provides events (ColumnChanged, RowChanged, RowDeleted, etc...) that allow you to track changes.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options how to figure out this. For example in my opinion I would make DataGridView ReadOnly and I would make one button for edit. When user click on this button it opens new Form and user can make editing there. Then if something happened in this form it will be saved (if changes are valid). This is how I do it.

Or maybe you just can set to save your changes everytime when user close the form. You have to count with wrong behaviour of user everytime... :)

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to the DataGridView's `CellValueChanged` event, and set a boolean flag saying the grid has been changed, then checked upon leaving the application.